# How do our eyes restructure the picture of objects "right side up"?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, vision

I hope I am posting this in the correct site. I am puzzled with the following sentence:

> [Time and space are compressed into a point of no dimension through which images of the things around us are restructured, as indeed **our eyes restructure for us the picture of the world upside down, right side up**.](https://books.google.com/books?id=szOPAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=Time%20and%20space%20are%20compressed%20into%20a%20point%20of%20no%20dimension%20through%20which%20images%20of%20the%20things%20around%20us%20are%20restructured,%20as%20indeed%20our%20eyes%20restructure%20for%20us%20the%20picture%20of%20the%20world%20upside%20down,%20right%20side%20up.&source=bl&ots=l8BovJw8oH&sig=wjo5NzHhe5isXKtoR86NRkfpQRw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4kZLys9PcAhVEhqQKHYazAWgQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=Time%20and%20space%20are%20compressed%20into%20a%20point%20of%20no%20dimension%20through%20which%20images%20of%20the%20things%20around%20us%20are%20restructured%2C%20as%20indeed%20our%20eyes%20restructure%20for%20us%20the%20picture%20of%20the%20world%20upside%20down%2C%20right%20side%20up.&f=false)

I can understand the "upside down" part, as our eyes turn things upside down as they receive them before they are processred by our mind, but what does "right side up" mean here. It is described as:

> [a direction in which the correct side of an object is facing up](http://grammarist.com/spelling/right-side-up/)

So if we are talking about a "bottle," for instance, does it refer to its outer surface not the inner one?

Or should I define the phrase as "the right [as opposed to the left] side of an object turned up"?

Comment: The actual physical image on the retina of the eye is upside-down.  The optic nerves and brain, however, interpret the image as right-side-up.  This is not surprising.  Even if the physical impulses arrived in the optic area of the brain in an inverted pattern (I'm not sure if this is well-defined), the brain is plastic enough to soon "learn" which way is up.  Most of what the brain does you don't have to think about.

Comment: This does not strike me as  a physics question.

Comment: The quoted text is discussing literature (comedy), not physics.

Comment: I'd say this is a duplicate of https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/337/why-would-the-brain-flip-the-images-perceived-by-your-eyes

Comment: This and the links therein may be of interest? https://www.theguardian.com/education/2012/nov/12/improbable-research-seeing-upside-down

Comment: @jcsahnwaldt It obviously does but the words in bold, I presume, deal with a physics question and I am trying to understand that part.

Comment: @developer It's not a physics question. It's a case of flowery language that is easily misunderstood. But you already found the answer: "a direction in which the correct side of an object is facing up" Correct. That's all there is to it. Question answered. "So if we are talking about a "bottle," for instance, does it refer to its outer surface not the inner one?" No. "Or should I define the phrase as "the right [as opposed to the left] side of an object turned up"?" No.

Comment: @jcsahnwaldt So you believe this "flowery language" is not correct and that the eye does not turn the picture of the object "right side up"?

Comment: @developer Correct. See https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/339/19616 (and many other sources) for details.

Comment: @jcsahnwaldt Thanks a lot for responding. Based on your comments, I think I need to choose Cleonis's answer which states the same thing.

Comment: @developer I think we should close this question since it's not a physics question.

Comment: To demonstrate that this is *not* a physics question you just need to read up on the [inverting glasses experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_M._Stratton#Wundt's_lab_and_the_inverted-glasses_experiments).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the subject has a congnitive rather than physical explanation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's how I see it: the last three words of that sentence must be omitted in order for it to make some sort of sense.

"Human eyes reshape for us the picture of the world upside down".

And even then that sentence is somewhat rambling. Chances are the source where you encountered that sentence is not a good source of information.

Comment: The sentence, actually, is not taken from a physics book, nor is it related to physics in general. But I am not sure if the writer is true by making such a claim. It actually belongs to a literary text. I update the quotation with the complete sentence, in case it works.

Answer (score -1):

The image on the retina is indeed upside down compared to the world out there. It is tempting to think of the brain as a "homunculus" -- a little man -- that then looks at this upside image, and conclude that some special work is needed to turn it around. We may feel even more confused learning that people rapidly adjust to wearing glasses that invert the image to be right side up!

However, the homunculus may be simple and thus tempting, but in the end useless.

It's better to think of the brain as building up a world model, starting in babyhood. As out bodies move the incoming sensory impressions vary. For example. if you tilt your head up, the world "slides down," the retinal image slides up, and the world models learns that "down" on the retina is like "up" in the outside world.

This stuff is very confusing when you first start thinking about it. A book I liked is Kevin O'Regan's "Why Red Doesn't Sound Like a Bell: Understanding the Feel of Consciousness"